# Open a pop up window on page load

Tags: 2013, 2010, javascript, popup

I will need to pop up a new window on page load in SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 pages.

I embedded the following code using the CEWP or Script Editor web part, but it doesn't work for me.

Can you please let me know how I should modify the code? Thanks

```
OnLoad="DesignerWizWin=window.open('http://www.designerwiz.com', `'DesignerWizWin', 'toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, menuBar=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, width=500, height=400, left=50, top=50');"`
```

Comment: Using `DesignerWizWin` the code would need to be inside `body`-element. Instead go with a simple JavaScript as [W3 guides](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I don't know how to add the code between the <body> tag  in SharePoint 2013 pages, can you please give me a clue?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the right approach would be to use the ModalWindowDialog from Sharepoint. To do this, add a scriptEditor webpart and add this:

```
function displayProfileLayover(url,windowTitle) {
      var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

      options.url=url;

        if (windowTitle) options.title=windowTitle;
        else options.title="";    //no popup window title
        options.showClose=true;
        options.autoSize=true;
        options.allowMaximize=true;
        //options.showMaximized=true;

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
```

Then, you could use that function to open a popup after page is fully loaded, doing somethink like this:

```
window.onload=displayProfileLayover('http://www.designerwiz.com', `'DesignerWizWin');
```

Or create the window only after the page load has been completed:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myCustomFunc);  //Execute only after page is fully loaded
     myCustomFunc(){ displayProfileLayover('http://www.designerwiz.com', `'DesignerWizWin'); }
```

You can search for all the options that this module offers over here ["sharepoint modal dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Quick question @Alberto, where would I have to add either of the two code snippets that calls the displayProfileLayover function? I couldn't get it to work thus far. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I just realized of some error in my description. Please read it again, it should work now :)

Comment: Thanks for updating but I still can't get it to work. Doesn't it work in SharePoint Online? What I did was insert a content editor webpart referencing a .js file that I uploaded to /SiteAssets. This .js file contains your code in the order your posted it minus the

    window.onload=displayProfileLayover('http://www.designerwiz.com', 
    `'DesignerWizWin');

part.

Comment: This is intended for sharepoint on premises. In spOnline it maybe another Js method. Add also the 'http(s)://' string. Window.onload maybe occur before the requires SP js file has been loaded. Use the eventListener described in my example.